# when to use mongodb's aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have researched the aggregate framework of mongodb 2.1. And I have done a test.

```
var drugstore = {
    id: 860011001238937,
    name: "store1",    
    transaction_flow: [
        {
        pepdate: 20120327,
        create_date: "2012-3-27 16:36:33",
        trace: "000256",
        peopleid: "123456",        
        tranamt: 1000,
       },
        {
        pepdate: 20120405,
        create_date: "2012-3-27 16:36:33",
        trace: "000256",
        peopleid: "123456",        
        tranamt: 1000,
       }
                ]
};
```

after I inserted 40 thousand datas into transaction_flow, the mongodb is crashed. And I know the limit size of  mongodb's document is 16Mb, now the drugstore collection is 22Mb. So the aggregate commands, ex. unwind, why design this command, and when to use?

Comment: Have you tried using is *across* documents? Right now you just have one massive document.

Comment: @Nik what is across document?

Comment: You only have a single document here - drugstore, and 40000 transaction_flows within it.  Instead what you probably want is to insert one document for drugstore, and 40000 distinct documents (not nested in drugstore) for transaction_flow.   Mongo works well with lots of small documents.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size to any result of MongoDB commands is limited to 64MB. There is an ongoing [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3253) that will add an out option similar to the map reduce command where you can potentially dump the result into a new collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but my question is the sub array objects of a document is limited by 16MB, and it can't meet my requirements.

Comment: @avatas: The current document limit (as of MongoDB 2.2) is 16Mb, and this is also the limit of results that can be returned via the Aggregation Framework or Map/Reduce with `inline` output.  If you are trying to return more than 16Mb of manipulated results, you would want to use Map/Reduce with [output to a collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions).